# Update the h4 text value of a module using querySelector

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I need to edit the text value of the h4 for this particular module of the site.

```
<div class="hero-wrapper">
<div class="hero-container">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br></p>
                                
<div class="form_component">
    <div class="register_container">
        <div id="register_form_wrapper">

            <h4 class="register-form_heading">Sign up before March 30th and get $50 promo coupon!</h4>

            
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I can only do it via the override JS tab of the CMS but my current script does not work as I am really not verse with this tech.

```
const formHeading = document.querySelector(".register_container .register-form_heading .h4");
formHeading.textContent = 'This is the updated text';
```

Comment: You don't have any element with the class `h4` so remove `.h4` from `.register-form_heading .h4`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the class of the h4. You don't need to go down layer by layer to get the nested element.

```
const formHeading = document.querySelector(".register_form_heading")
formHeading.textContent= "This is the updated text"
```

Also "register-form_heading" is a badly named class. I think you should use either hyphens or underscores only.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback even if the suggested solution didn't work. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector `h4.register-form_heading` to match a `<h4>` element with the `register-form-heading` class.

```js
const formHeading = document.querySelector(".register_container h4.register-form_heading");
formHeading.textContent = 'This is the updated text';
```

```html
<div class="hero-wrapper">
  <div class="hero-container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br></p>
    <div class="form_component">
      <div class="register_container">
        <div id="register_form_wrapper">
          <h4 class="register-form_heading">Sign up before March 30th and get $50 promo coupon!</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```